# What happens to the author's reputation when you flag his work?

Tags: discussion, flags

Will a user's reputation be affected if his comment, question or answer is flagged? I know reputation is affected by down-votes but what about flags? Also will the user be notified if his comment was flagged?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comment-flags - like everything else connected to comments - have absolutely no effect on reputation.

Post flags - those raised on questions and answers - *can* affect reputation in the following scenarios:

- Spam and Offensive flags cause an automatic downvote (from [the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user)) when raised. This vote is removed if the flags are dismissed without action, but result in a total penalty of -100 [if the post is deleted as a result](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work).
- Very Low Quality flags [cause an automatic downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous/93606#93606) *if they're marked as helpful*.

No other flags have any direct effects on reputation.

Authors are not notified of flags, and cannot see them when they exist, although they are able to observe the presence of down-votes if those are generated.

#### See also:

- [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)